# How to draw an area on a map colored by a gradient?

Tags: javascript, gis, here-api

I'd like to draw a shape (say a rectangle, for simplicity's sake) covering an area with a color that changes shade from e.g. green to red. Is the only approach drawing a gazillion small rectangles with colors shifting by an index or is there a way to state a gradiental from-to (or even better, from-through-to) color array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you can use a html canvas to create gradient and fill your shape with it (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_createlineargradient.asp).

Or you can use a svg gradient (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Gradients).

Also you may try to use a html map area with some plugins.

For your map polygons drawn like [this](https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/v3.0/geoshapes/polygon-on-the-map). Parameters for them are described [here](https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics_api_nlp/h-map-spatialstyle-options.html#h-map-spatialstyle-options__fillcolor)‌​. It seems that they support only colors without gradients, but as an option you can try overlay like [this](https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/v3.0/infoBubbles/custom-tile-overlay)‌​.

Comment: I don't have any example yet because I'm at the designing stage and trying to work out the tricky details. But if you imagine that you have two points (or more in reality) with the values of -5 and +23 with corresponding colors of red and green, then I'd like to draw circles interpolating the values in between. Such a solution I can do using D3 but now I want to **somehow** jack it into the map from Here. And that's where I get stuck...

Comment: You can change your map to Google Maps or to use the api for your map:
They support svg, so you can make a figure in svg with gradient and use it (https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/v3.0/markers/map-with-svg-graphic-markers).
You can also use the dom marker (https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/v3.0/markers/map-with-dom-marker) with css gradient (http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)
You can try to deal with this (https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/data-lens/data_lens/telco-heatmap3)

Comment: For your map polygons drawn like this (https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/v3.0/geoshapes/polygon-on-the-map) parameters for them are described here (https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics_api_nlp/h-map-spatialstyle-options.html#h-map-spatialstyle-options__fillcolor).
It seems that they support only colors without gradients, but as an option you can try overlay (https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/v3.0/infoBubbles/custom-tile-overlay).

Comment: Awesome comments, mate! I took the liberty to incorporate the best part into the answer. Great!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Google Map, you could try [Heatmaps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap) with gradients

Comment: That's precisely what I'm aiming for. Is there a generic solution that isn't bound to Google Maps specifically? I'm working with Here Maps.

Comment: I don't feel we have a generic solution for this. But you can extend the Map solution which you use to support gradient layers with the @Sergey Yastrebov solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really after a heatmap, as suggested in your comment in @jaganathan-bantheswaran answer, then you will be able to do this in HERE Maps using the [H.data.heatmap.Provider](https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics_api_nlp/h-data-heatmap-provider.html) class

The API Reference describes how to do this:

```
// Create heat map provider
var heatmapProvider = new H.data.heatmap.Provider({
  colors: new H.data.heatmap.Colors({
  '0': 'blue',
  '0.5': 'yellow',
  '1': 'red'
  }, true),
  // paint assumed values in regions where no data is available
  assumeValues: true
});

// Add the data
heatmapProvider.addData([
  {lat: 52, lng: 1, value: 1},
  {lat: 53, lng: 2, value: 2}
]);

// Create semi transparent heat map layer
var heatmapLayer = new H.map.layer.TileLayer(heatmapProvider, {
  opacity: 0.6
});

// Add layer to the map
map.addLayer(heatmapLayer);
```